# Where can I find more Gmail themes?

Tags: gmail

Is there somewhere I can find Gmail themes besides the ones that are available by default?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, if you use Chrome or Firefox, you can install the Stylish plug-in - [Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/stylish/), [Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe) - which allows you to use your own stylesheets for the sites you visit. Then, go to the [public themes directory](http://userstyles.org/styles/browse/google/Gmail) and search for existing Gmail themes.

Answer (score 3):

Gmail Themes are only provided by Gmail's Developers and cannot be added externally.